# Changing global variable via method in tkinter

Tags: python, methods, tkinter, optionmenu

I've done some research to find out that to change the global variable within a method in python you have to pass `global variablename`, then continue to change it with the method. I'm trying to change a variable to true based on a tkinter Optionmenu selection, but to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Verifiable Example:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *


AllCheck = False

filterList = ["All"]

GuiWindow = Tk()

def change_dropdown(*args):
    if FilterChoiceVar.get() is "All":
        global AllCheck
        AllCheck = True
        return AllCheck

def scanBus():

    change_dropdown()

    if scanvar.get():
        if AllCheck == True:
            print("AllCheck in action!")
        else:
            pass

FilterChoiceVar = StringVar(GuiWindow)
FilterChoiceVar.set("All")
FilterChoice = OptionMenu(
GuiWindow, FilterChoiceVar, *filterList)

scanvar = BooleanVar()

scanbtn = Checkbutton(
    GuiWindow,
    text="scan",
    variable=scanvar,
    command=scanBus,
    indicatoron=0)

scanbtn.grid(row=1, column=0)
FilterChoice.grid(row=0, column=0)


GuiWindow.geometry('{}x{}'.format(100, 50))
GuiWindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: You don't seem to be doing anything wrong. Please add a [mcve] to your question. `change_dropdown` absolutely will change the global variables when called, assuming one of the conditions is True.

Comment: I just uploaded a verifiable example, thanks for the input

Comment: We don't need duplicate code. Please just have a single program that is as minimal as possible. You can cut this program down a lot for the purposes of this question. For example, you don't need three global variables to illustrate a problem in setting one global variable.

Comment: Understood. I'll update the post, just didn't want to leave anything important out.

Comment: Also, verify that your `if` statements are doing what you think they should (hint: they are not). You need to do some basic debugging before you ask a question like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem comes from the `FilterChoiceVar.get() is "All"` expression which is never True. A good practice is to always use '==' instead of 'is' to compare strings. Here is my modified code, including some code cleaning:

```
from tkinter import *

AllCheck = False
filterList = ["All","Not All"]

def check_dropdown(*args):
    global AllCheck
    AllCheck = FilterChoiceVar.get() == "All"

def scanBus():
    check_dropdown()
    if ScanVar.get() and AllCheck:
        print("AllCheck in action!")

GuiWindow = Tk()

FilterChoiceVar = StringVar(GuiWindow)
FilterChoiceVar.set("Not All")
FilterChoice = OptionMenu(GuiWindow, FilterChoiceVar, *filterList)
FilterChoice.grid(row=0, column=0)

ScanVar = BooleanVar()
ScanButton = Checkbutton(GuiWindow, text="scan", variable=ScanVar,
                         command=scanBus, indicatoron=0)
ScanButton.grid(row=1, column=0)

GuiWindow.geometry('{}x{}'.format(100, 60))
GuiWindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you are going to speak on good practice then you should correct bad practices in the code such as importing tkinter twice.

Comment: @Mike: I just paste the initial code and didn't notice that it included double import. You're a bit harsh to vote -1 for such a light mistake :)

Comment: Its not harsh at all. Bad code is bad code. Now that you have made the change I can change my vote.